# Python: Wait until c# dll method finishes execution

Tags: c#, python, dll

I've written an c# code that calculates the exponential of a number and returns the value. I've created an DLL using it.

```
namespace sampleNamespace
{
    public class ExpClass
    {
        public float exp(float a)
        {
             //Calculate exponential
             return exponentialValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm loading the c# DLL in Python and invoking the `add(int a, int b)` from Python.

```
import dotnet.seamless
dotnet.add_assemblies(".")
dotnet.load_assembly("ExpDLL")

#Import namespace from c#
import sampleNamespace

expClass = sampleNamespace.ExpClass()

exp = 0
exp= expClass.exp(7.9865)
print("Computation completed:", exp)
```

While running the above python, the print statement gets printed without waiting for the DLL method to get completed. I'm getting the below output?

```
Computation completed: 0
```

How can I make the main thread of Python to wait for the `expClass.exp()` to complete and then continue?

Comment: Your C# code won't compile, you return value in `void` method.

Comment: Sorry, i typed it wrongly in stackoverflow. I'm returning a float in the real code.

Comment: The code you supplied doesn't compile, obviously, so it's impossible to tell what's going wrong -- but one thing's certain, it won't be that the Python code "doesn't wait" for the method to complete. How have you verified the method doesn't actually return 0? Have you called it from C# code with the argument `7.9865`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, verified that from c#. Unfortunately I can't share the code, very sorry for that. But this is the jist of it.